# Zabbix: How to configure a trigger which notifies me that a certain error has arised twice?

Tags: monitoring, web, zabbix

I need to configure a Zabbix check which will check access to a certain internet page.
The page can return `http status 200 (ok)` or `500 (internal server error)`.
I want to get a Zabbix notification when ever a `500 status error` arises twice, is that possible?

Edit #1:
@Tero Kilkanen: This is the error I get when I try to create the trigger:

```
Incorrect trigger expression. Check expression part starting from "{Mobit engine health check:web.test.rspcode[Check engine,engine health check].count(10,"500 (internal server error)","eq")".
```

Edit #2:
I've created the web scenario as follows:
[image]
And the single step:
[image]
I've created the next trigger:
[image]
And here's the `Lastest Data` from the Zabbix server:
[image]
But then I have two questions:

```
1. How can I check that the trigger works if it is not displayed in `Latest Data` in the Zabbix server?
2. How do I edit the trigger to reflect the needed configuration? which is to raise and alert when http status returns `500 Internal server error` twice?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

First you need to create a web check with instructions at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/web_monitoring

Then, after making the test, you get new items, which you can use in a trigger. In your case, you want to check the HTTP error code, so the trigger would be like:

{HOST:web.test.error[TESTNAME].count(10,500)}>1

Here, HOST means the host which is configured to make the web check. TESTNAME is the name given to the web check scenario.

The first argument `10` to coint() means that it counts events happening in last ten seconds. The second argument contains the error code to compare against. The trigger launches if there are more than 1 instance of 500 errors in last 10 seconds.

For further information on `count` syntax, look at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how do I create the correct Item as well?

Comment: You need to implement a web check, https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/web_monitoring has good instructions for doing that. After creating the web check, you will have an item `web.test.error`, which is the HTTP status code.

Comment: But this web check describes a scenario... i need only to access a web page and get it's status code... is that the only way to do it? by creating a scenario?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a one-step web check scenario.

Comment: I updated the answer for completeness. I think you were checking for the wrong value in the web check scenario.

Comment: Use the trigger in my answer, you have made some other trigger here. You also have configured the step incorrectly, you require `200` status code that indicates the web check works correctly.

Comment: I just did, and I get this error:
Incorrect item key "web.test.error[check engine http status 500,check engine http status,resp]" provided for trigger expression on "HOSTNAME".
while unable to save the trigger...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible do it. Create the trigger below:

```
{HOST:web.test.rspcode[SCENARIO,STEP].diff(200)}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Not a good idea, cause e.g. `301` doesn't mean an error. Most time it's just a desired redirect `http->https` or smth like this

Comment: How do you tell to send the alert only after it is returning 500 for a consecutive 5 requests?